# What is meant by a "copy" of one field in another?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, intuition

My first language isn't English so I need an explanation for this problem:

**Every field of characteristic zero contains a copy of the rationals.**

In the proof they defined a homomorphism between rationals and a field and proved it was injective!
What does copy mean?

My guess is that they mean the field has a subset isomorphic to the rationals. But then how does proving there is a homomorphism between rationals and the field help?

Comment: Your guess is correct. An **injective** homomorphism $h:\Bbb Q\to F$ is an isomorphism between $\Bbb Q$ and $h[\Bbb Q]$, so $h[\Bbb Q]$ is a copy of the rationals in $F$.

Comment: How does it help **what**?

Comment: Just note that the homomorphism you need is an injective field homomorphism (so that it preserves the field properties). Then you can treat the image of the homomorphism as if the image elements are rational numbers. Also note that this injective homomorphism of the rationals is unique - there isn't another one, so there is a unique way of identifying "rational numbers" inside the field you are given. As the subject develops you will find that you can have fields $K$ and $L$ where you can find many copies of $L$ inside $K$. So the embedding of the rationals is a special and fundamental one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that an object $X$ is a copy of an object $Y$ means that $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$. In your example it can be shown that each field $K$ of characteristic zero contains a subfield $ Q \subset K$ which is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb Q$ of rationals. The proof you mentioned constructs a homomorphism $f : \mathbb Q \to K$ and shows that it is injective. Then $Q = f(\mathbb Q)$ is the desired subfield.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an injective homomorphism $\varphi\colon\Bbb Q\longrightarrow k$, where $k$ is your field, then $\varphi(\Bbb Q)$ and $\Bbb Q$ are isomorphic fields and $\varphi(\Bbb Q)$ is a subfield of $k$. But it is also isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$. Therefore, it behaves as a copy of $\Bbb Q$ inside $k$.